# How to create a sub accordion?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I created accordion links on my site. How to create a sub accordion ?

thank you

Here is my html code :

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-lg"></i> Ses contenus <span class="badge"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_2') }}</dd></span>
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse11">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
              <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-lg"></i> Les annonces <span class="badge"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_2') }}</dd></span>
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_1') }}</dd></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main accordion is "Ses contenus" and the sub accordion "Les annonces". My problem, when I open the sub accordion, the main accordion closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. You were giving the same `id` to two different `accordions` so your main `accordion` was also getting triggered. Check the example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-lg"></i> Ses contenus <span class="badge"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_2') }}</dd></span>
        </h4>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse11">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
              <i class="fa fa-object-group fa-lg"></i> Les annonces <span class="badge"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_2') }}</dd></span>
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body"><dd>{{ drupal_view('profil_page_contenu_utilisateur', 'block_1') }}</dd></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But there is a second problem. When I open a sub accordion in main accordion 1 and open 2 main accordion 2, main accordion 1 closes but the sub accordion remains open in main bow 1. You can test on the page of my site.

Comment: You need to give a unique `id` to each `accordion`, in your previous code you gave the same `id` to both the `accordions`. Check if you are giving each `accordion` a different `id`.